# How can I capture the DNS servers for a client computer with .cmd or powershell?

Tags: php, powershell, dns, wmi, wmic

I need to capture the DNS servers used by a Windows 10 client into a text file in the simplest way possible.
Possibilities that came to mind include querying wmi via a batch command or command line, or using Powershell.

Powershell with the following command line works, but is verbose and I only want the one line with the ipv4 addresses if possible.

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias ethernet > c:\temp\DNS2.txt
```

Ultimately I'll be using PHP on an internal site to pick that up and work with it.  I'm assuming that PHP can't read that sort of data directly, so my plan is to have a scheduled task update the text file on the client periodically and let PHP read it in from the text file.

Comment: N.B. PHP running on a server won't be able to read a text file on a client-side machine (unless client and server are both on the same LAN and you share the folder containing the text file). Why does a PHP website need to know this info though? Can't help feeling there could be a better approach to whatever you're trying to achieve, architecturally.

Comment: So you just want this?
`(Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -AddressFamily IPv4).Address  | Out-File c:\temp\DNS2.txt`

Comment: @ADyson, I suspect you're right.  So here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
I'm tending my 95 year old father-in-law's computer, which he is constantly getting infected with malware.  Recently, I realized his DNS servers have been changed somehow from OpenDNS which I set to try to block some of the malware sites.
I have a simple portal page on my server that gives him links to his email, news sites, etc. 
What I'm trying to do is show the DNS servers from his ethernet connection on his portal page, so that I can call him and say "Hey Fred, what does it say after DNS on your home page?"

Comment: Ok, I see. Is the portal page on the same local area network as the computer in question? If not, is the portal on the public internet, or within your own separate local network?

Comment: As an aside, if it was me, I would threaten to install Ubuntu if he doesn't take better care of what he's downloading or what dodgy sites he's visiting which are resulting in this malware epidemic, and/or install some parental controls and treat it like a child's device!! All my elderly relatives use Linux, and aside from the occasional complaint about incompatible apps (which has greatly decreased over the years now they can do almost all tasks in a browser), I get no hassle at all in terms of maintenance :-).

Comment: @ADyson  I suspect you're right.  And I'm making the classic error of assuming that my development environment represents real world.  /FACEPALM

I'm going to re-post the question and explain better what I'm trying to accomplish.

And I'm afraid Linus is a non-starter. Change is not welcomed with open arms.

Comment: Fair enough, at that age. Just a thought: to overcome the network issue you could have a script on his machine which uploads the data to something like dropbox or onedrive at regular intervals (using a scheduled task to control it), and then another on your side which downloads it to your website. But the portal page would still need to be in a public place where he can view it from his side, and of course if something messes with his DNS entries and stop it being accessible, then you're no better off. Hm.

Comment: Of course you _could_ put the portal page actually on his device, either as a desktop app, or using a local webserver...

Comment: P.S. Have you managed to get any idea of where the malware is coming from? Might be time to back up his data, rebuild the machine, ensure virus and malware scanning is on, maybe add some sort of filtering via his ISP and router, and ensure the account he logs onto the PC with isn't an admin account, so he can't accidentally install junk. That would lock it down as much as is reasonable without interfering with his usage too much, I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-AddressFamily` parameter to filter for IPv4 only, then use `ForEach-Object` to extract the potential values from `ServerAddresses`:

```
@(
  Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias ethernet -AddressFamily IPv4 |ForEach-Object ServerAddresses
) -join ' ' |Add-Content C:\temp\DNS2.txt
```